# Change the value in std::map from iterator

Tags: c++, stdmap

My application merges two `std::map` instances. If there are no duplicates, the merge completes without intervention. However, if a duplicate is detected, then the method asks whether the new value should be ignored or overwritten. (This query may be answered by a rule table, message box to the user, or some other logic ... it is just an instance of a class derived from a pure virtual class with a `bool confirm() const` method.)

If the insert fails, and they decide to overwrite the existing entry, I already have an iterator pointing to the correct item to update. Can I use this iterator to update the value directly, or do I have to call `operator[]` and take the hit of another lookup?

```
// typedef std::map<Foo, Foo, Compare> Dictionary;
// Dictionary this_dictionary, other_dictionary;
for (Dictionary::const_iterator i = other_dictionary.begin();
     i != other_dictionary.end();
     ++i) {
  std::pair<Dictionary::iterator,bool> ret = this_dictionary.insert(*i);
  if (!ret.second && confirmer.confirm()) {
    // ???
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Dictionary::iterator` instead of `Dictionary::const_iterator` in the return from insert.

```
for (Dictionary::const_iterator i = other_dictionary.begin();
     i != other_dictionary.end();
     ++i) {
  // Use standard iterator here
  std::pair<Dictionary::iterator,bool> ret = this_dictionary.insert(*i);
  if (!ret.second && confirmer.confirm()) {
    ret.first->second = i->first; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course! For some reason I was thinking `pair<const Key, T>::second` would return an unmodifiable copy of the value. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you need to use iterator instead of const_iterator.

Comment: OK, but then what do you do with the iterator? (I modified the original question; the const_iterator was a copy-and-paste error; my actual code has a bunch more typedefs that I removed to post on SO and was using the non-const iterator here.)

Comment: You modify the value of `ret.first->second`.